# Firebase missing or insufficient permissions only on first render

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Here are my Firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  // Users
    match /users/{user} {
      allow read, update: if request.auth != null;
      allow create, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.admin == true;

    }
    
    // folders
    match /folders/{folder} {
      allow read, create, delete, update: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.admin == true;
      // allow read: if true;

    }
  }
}
```

**When first logging in**, I'm getting this error message: missing or insufficient permissions

After refreshing the page, everything renders fine.

This makes me think that the authenticated state if not being immediately validated (because the error happens only on first render)

In my rules when I set everything to:

```
allow read: if true;
```

Everything works fine. This seems to be causing the problem:

```
if request.auth != null;
```

Any way to solve this error?

UPDATE: the error in the console is taking me to this hook:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { auth } from '../../firebase';

function useAdminStatus() {
  const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAdmin = async () => {
      const idTokenResult = await auth?.currentUser?.getIdTokenResult();
      if (idTokenResult?.claims?.admin) {
        setIsAdmin(true);
      } else {
        setIsAdmin(false);
      }
    };

    checkAdmin();
  });

  return { isAdmin };
}

export default useAdminStatus;
```

Anything wrong with it?

Comment: Have you considered that this can be caused by the react code?

Comment: Could be. I am making a fetch call to firebase in a component shared by both admins and users.

Comment: If the error only happen on first render, I think it might be worth to check how login is handled as well.